# Multiple switches (toggels) enable all at once when generated from array react-native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Right now I got an array like this in my constructor:

```
    words: ['test', 'test', 'test'],
```

Inside the render I want to generate an element with a text and switch (toggle) for every element like this:

```
const wordList = this.state.words.map((item, i) =>
    <View style={styles.wordsContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.pilgrimsWordText} key={i}>{item}</Text>
      <Switch
        style={styles.pilgrimsWordSwitch}
        onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({ toggled: value })}}
        value={ this.state.toggled }
      />
    </View>
 )
```

after that I just show the elements inside the return.

The elements get generated and everything looks fine but when a user press one of the sitches (toggle) all of them get enabled like on the picture:

## [picture of the elements (with text and switches)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNLou.png)

What would you do to just enable the one switch (toggle) the user wishes to enable?

__________ edited :___________
Here is my constructor:

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     words: [{ id: 1, text: 'test'}, { id: 2, text: 'test'}, {id: 3, text: 'test'}],
     textInputValue: '',
   }
  }
```

And now the map look like this after:

```
const wordList = this.state.words.map((item, i) =>
    <View style={styles.wordsContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.pilgrimsWordText} key={item.id}>{item.text}</Text>
      <Switch
        style={styles.pilgrimsWordSwitch}
        onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({ toggled: { [item.id]: value }})}}
        value={ this.state.toggled[item.id] }
      />
    </View>
 )
```

And here is the error:

[image: image of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to track the element index and restructure your data for `words` like in my example:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      words: [
        {text: 'test', toggled: false},
        {text: 'test', toggled: false},
        {text: 'test', toggled: false}
      ]
    }
  }

  toggle(index, e){
    const words = [...this.state.words];
    words[index].toggled = !words[index].toggled;

    this.setState({ words });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.words.map((word, i) =>
            <span key={i}>
              {word.text}
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggle.bind(this, i)} />
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   //bind a function with element index you just clicked
            </span>
        )}
        <br/><br/>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.words)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/162864/)

Comment: I just mixed your answear with mine and it work, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because each mapped component is using the same state variable to determine if it's in the 'toggled' state or not. You would need to use 3 different state variables but if the length of the list is unknown this becomes a lot harder.

Comment: The length is unknown. I'm aware of the state problem I just don't know how to fix it or do something else :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique identifier in your data/array to achieve desiref behavior.

If you make a change to your data like below you can set unique state values to each mapped component.

```
words: [{ id: 1, text: 'test'}, { id: 2, text: 'test'}, {id: 3, text: 'test'}],
```

---

```
const wordList = this.state.words.map((item, i) =>
    <View style={styles.wordsContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.pilgrimsWordText} key={item.id}>{item.text}</Text>
      <Switch
        style={styles.pilgrimsWordSwitch}
        onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({ toggled: { [item.id]: value })}}
        value={ this.state.toggled[item.id] }
      />
    </View>
 )
```

In constructor set your initial toggled state value to an empty object like this `{}`

Comment: I get this error when trying to use your example: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.state.toggled[item.id] do you know why?

Comment: Can you update your question with the current state of your code please. Don't delete your previous version. Just add below. Also please add your contructor code too.

Comment: @MaikenMadsen like I told you in my answer, you need to initit the toggle value in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Array.map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, the callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the **element** {}, the **index of the element**, and the **Array object** being traversed.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Switch,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class WordList extends Component {

  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      words: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Notification', toggle:false}, 
        { id: 2, text: 'Wifi', toggle:false}, 
        { id: 3, text: 'Bluetooth', toggle:false}
      ]
    }
  };

 renderWordList(){
    const wordList = this.state.words.map((word, i, wordArray) =>
      <View key={word.id} style={styles.wordsContainer}>
        <Text>{word.text}</Text>
        <Switch
          style={styles.pilgrimsWordSwitch}
          onValueChange={(toggleValue) => {
            wordArray[i].toggle = toggleValue;
            this.setState({words: wordArray});
          }}
          value={ word.toggle }
        />
      </View>
    )
    return wordList;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor: 'gray'}}>
        {this.renderWordList()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wordsContainer: {
    alignItems:'center', 
    backgroundColor:'green',  
    flexDirection:'row',
    height:100, 
    ustifyContent:'center', 
    padding:20,
  },
  pilgrimsWordSwitch: {
    flex:1, 
    justifyContent:'flex-end'
  }
});
```

[image: Render View of above Code]