# How to have multiple independent switches in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am having 5 switches in an activity which are working fine. But the problem is that all are interlinked with each other i.e, If one switch is turned on, all the switches get turn on.

How to do them independent switches by which they do not gets affected on other switch action?

My Code -

```
state = {
    colorTrueSwitchIsOn: true,
    colorFalseSwitchIsOn: false,
};

class Notification extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({
        navigation
    }) => ({
        header: props => < Header
        navigation = {
            navigation
        }
        title = {
            'NOTIFICATION SETTINGS'
        }
        toggleDrawer /
        >
    })

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            SwitchOnValueHolder: false

        };
    }



    ShowAlert = (value) => {

        this.setState({

            SwitchOnValueHolder: value
        })

        if (value == true) {

            //Perform any task here which you want to execute on Switch ON event.
            Toast.show('Switch is On');
        }
        else {

            //Perform any task here which you want to execute on Switch OFF event.
            Toast.show('Switch is On');
        }

    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            View style = {
                styles.container
            } >

            <
            ScrollView >



            <
            View style = {
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }
            } >




            <
            View style = {
                {
                    width: '25%',
                    height: 50,
                }
            } >

            <
            Switch onValueChange = {
                (value) => this.setState({
                    colorTrueSwitchIsOn: value
                })
            }
            onTintColor = "#FFE2C6"
            thumbTintColor = "#FF952E"
            tintColor = "#D7D0C9"
            value = {
                this.state.colorTrueSwitchIsOn
            }
            />

            <
            /View>

            <
            /View>


            <
            View style = {
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }
            } >




            <
            View style = {
                {
                    width: '25%',
                    height: 50,
                }
            } >

            <
            Switch onValueChange = {
                (value) => this.setState({
                    colorTrueSwitchIsOn: value
                })
            }
            onTintColor = "#FFE2C6"
            thumbTintColor = "#FF952E"
            tintColor = "#D7D0C9"
            value = {
                this.state.colorTrueSwitchIsOn
            }
            />

            <
            /View>

            <
            /View>


            <
            View style = {
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    marginBottom: 20
                }
            } >




            <
            View style = {
                {
                    width: '25%',
                    height: 50,
                    top: 10
                }
            } >

            <
            Switch onValueChange = {
                (value) => this.setState({
                    colorTrueSwitchIsOn: value
                })
            }
            onTintColor = "#FFE2C6"
            thumbTintColor = "#FF952E"
            tintColor = "#D7D0C9"
            value = {
                this.state.colorTrueSwitchIsOn
            }
            />

            <
            /View>

            <
            /View>


            <
            View style = {
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }
            } >




            <
            View style = {
                {
                    width: '25%',
                    height: 50,
                }
            } >

            <
            Switch onValueChange = {
                (value) => this.setState({
                    colorTrueSwitchIsOn: value
                })
            }
            onTintColor = "#FFE2C6"
            thumbTintColor = "#FF952E"
            tintColor = "#D7D0C9"
            value = {
                this.state.colorTrueSwitchIsOn
            }
            />

            <
            /View>

            <
            /View>


            <
            View style = {
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }
            } >




            <
            View style = {
                {
                    width: '25%',
                    height: 50,
                }
            } >

            <
            Switch onValueChange = {
                (value) => this.setState({
                    colorTrueSwitchIsOn: value
                })
            }
            onTintColor = "#FFE2C6"
            thumbTintColor = "#FF952E"
            tintColor = "#D7D0C9"
            value = {
                this.state.colorTrueSwitchIsOn
            }
            />

            <
            /View>

            <
            /View>

            <
            /View>

            <
            /ScrollView>

            <
            /View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
    },

    layout: {
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginLeft: 15,
        marginRight: 10,
    }

})

export default Notification
```

How do I solve this bug?
I tried it to call as different switches which didn't work!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646872/multiple-switches-toggels-enable-all-at-once-when-generated-from-array-react-n/49688175#49688175) link may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have linked all the switch values to the same state variable; colorTrueSwitchIsOn. And also all the onValueChange methods change the same variable. Is there a specific reason you want to do it in this way? Because this is the problem.

Each switch's `value` and `onValueChange` method should be linked with a different state variable.

Have separate values in your state:

```
this.state = {
    switchVal1: true,
    switchVal2: false
};
```

And then link your switches to their variables separately:

```
<Switch onValueChange = {(value) => this.setState({switchVal1: value})}
    value = {this.state.switchVal1}/>


<Switch onValueChange = {(value) => this.setState({switchVal2: value})}
    value = {this.state.switchVal2}/>
```